# condition in template function implementation depending on whether the type is a pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

So I have this template function.
It's supposed to set a variable in a more complex structure called `AbstractEvent`:

```
template< typename T >

void AbstractEvent::setVar( QString varName, T value) 
{
    if (std::is_pointer<T>::value)
    {
        void * castValue = static_cast<void*>(value);
        if (castValue)
        {
            //do sth with castValue
        }

     }
     else
     {
        //do something with value
     }
}
```

With this template function, I would like to store the variable "value" in a QVariant and then store the QVariant somewhere.

If "value" is a pointer, I would like to store it as a void* in the QVariant. For anything else I'd like to store the real type.

I tried using the C++ trait std::is_pointer::value  to check whether value is a pointer or not.

This code compiles fine, but when I try to use it, with, for example :

```
int intValue = 0;
setVar<int>("aVar",intValue);
```

I get this error :

```
error C2440: 'static_cast' : unable to convert from 'int' to 'void *'
```

I think the compiler is confused because it's checking this line :

```
    void * castValue = static_cast<void*>(value);
```

which, of course, makes no sense when value is not a pointer. That's what my if statement

```
     if (std::is_pointer<T>::value)
```

was supposed to avoid, but, even if at run time, this piece of code with value as an int will never be executed, at compile time it confuses the compiler... Is there a work around for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tag dispatch:

```
template< typename T >
void AbstractEvent::setVar_impl( QString varName, T value, std::true_type /*is_ptr*/) 
{
    void * castValue = static_cast<void*>(value);
    if (castValue)
    {
            //do sth with castValue
    }
}

template< typename T >
void AbstractEvent::setVar_impl( QString varName, T value, std::false_type /*is_ptr*/) 
{
    //do something with value
}

template< typename T >
void AbstractEvent::setVar( QString varName, T value){
    setVar_impl(varName, value, std::is_pointer<T>());
}
```

Alternatively, overload and then SFINAE out the inapplicable one:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type 
AbstractEvent::setVar(QString varName, T value) 
{
    void * castValue = static_cast<void*>(value);
    if (castValue)
    {
            //do sth with castValue
    }
}

template< typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>::type 
AbstractEvent::setVar( QString varName, T value) 
{
    //do something with value
}
```

Third alternative, overload directly:

```
template< typename T >
void AbstractEvent::setVar( QString varName, T* value) 
{
    void * castValue = static_cast<void*>(value);
    if (castValue)
    {
            //do sth with castValue
    }
}

template< typename T >
void AbstractEvent::setVar( QString varName, T value) 
{
    //do something with value
}
```

The first template is more specialized than the second by partial ordering, so will be chosen if both are equally viable.

You may also want to special case the `T == nullptr_t` case. `nullptr_t` isn't a pointer type, but you probably want the pointer overload to be called in that situation.

Answer (score 5):

Simple overloading, anyone?

```
template<typename T>
void AbstractEvent::setVar(QString varName, T value);

template<typename T>
void AbstractEvent::setVar(QString varName, T* value);
```

Comment: I need to start attending Complexity Anonymous.

Answer (score 3):

You can also hold on to your design by using `std::conditional`:

```
typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_pointer<T>::value, void*, T>::type cast_type;
auto castValue = static_cast<cast_type>(value);
```

However, the solutions using tag dispatching or overloading -- though longer -- are maybe a bit clearer.